# How to change the debug.keystore location in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-keystore

I am using **Ubuntu** for Android Development. I launch Android Studio as a root user every time. So my SDK files are all located at `/root/Android/Sdk.`

I also have my **debug.keystore** file located at

```
/root/.android/debug.keystore
```

But whenever I run my app the following error shows up

```
/home/USERNAME/.android/debug.keystore (No such file or directory)
```

Looks like Android Studio is looking for the debug.keystore inside `/home/USERNAME/.android/debug.keystore` instead of `/root/.android/debug.keystore` and hence the error.

How could I change this and force Android Studio to look for the debug.keystore file in my `/root/.android` directory?

> One solution I thought of was to launch Android Studio as a local user
>   (non-root user), so that everything fits up. But that'll have two
>   installations of Android Studio on my system (one as root and one as
>   local user) and I don't want that.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can specify the keystore location in your app's build.gradle file like:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("/root/.android/debug.keystore")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally I don't think running apps as root is a good idea though.

Comment: Yes sir. Your solution worked for me. I'll accept this as the right solution in a few minutes. And about your advise, yes I know I shoudn't run as root user but due to some permission issues I had to be root for a certain project. Thank you so much